# Call function in event callback

Tags: solidity, events

I have a contract that sends an event when the transaction is done. In my React/Web3 application, I'm listening to this event and when it's triggered I would like to run another function.

My code looks like this:

```
listenToMyEvent = async () => {
    const { accounts, contract } = this.state;
    await contract.events.MyEvent().on("data", async function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
        await this.getSuccessCount();
    });
}

getSuccessCount = async () => {
    const { contract } = this.state;
    const count = await contract.methods.getCount().call();
    console.log(count);
}
```

Receiving an event works great. Also method `getSuccessCount` works well when I invoke it from outside of the event callback. My problem is that when I invoke `await getSuccessCount();` from inside of the event callback I'm getting the following error:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getSuccessCount is not a function`

How can I invoke getSuccessCount from inside of event listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `this` keyword inside a function callback, the scope of `this` is the function itself. Something like this should work as the scope of `this` won't conflict inside the callback.

```js
listenToMyEvent = async () => {
    const { accounts, contract } = this.state;
    const getSuccessCount = this.getSuccessCount;
    
    async function eventCallback(event){
        console.log(event);
        await getSuccessCount();
    }
   
    await contract.events.MyEvent().on("data",eventCallback);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this works great. THX!